# Why I receive error: table doesn't exist, when I run my Zend Framework 2 app to remote server?

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

I have created a RESTful zend2 app which is working fine on my localhost. Now I want to deploy it on the remote server and I get some errors related to the Adabter. I am new to zend framework and I am not sure why I get any errors, as I double checked every thing to be correct. I searched this error on the net, but I could not find any useful answer related to Zend2.

I exported the whole localhost database and imported it to the remote database and changed all the database credentials in local.php and global.php to the new database in the new host. Now when I want to access the database part of the app, in the module(Like myApp/user which it supposed to give me the list of the users in the db in json format), It gives me the following errors (I am sorry if I am giving to much error messages. I just want my question to be detailed):

File:

```
/var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-db/src/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Statement.php:244
```

Message:

```
Statement could not be executed: 42S02 - 1146 - Table 'myAppDatabase.User' doesn't exist
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-db/src/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php(238): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement->execute()
#1 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-db/src/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php(208): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->executeSelect(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#2 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-db/src/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php(195): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->selectWith(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#3 /var/www/myApp/module/User/src/User/Model/UserTable.php(17): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->select()
#4 /var/www/myApp/module/User/src/User/Controller/UserController.php(40): User\Model\UserTable->fetchAll()
#5 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractRestfulController.php(370): User\Controller\UserController->getList()
#6 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#7 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#9 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#10 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractRestfulController.php(300): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#11 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#12 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#13 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#14 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#15 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#16 /var/www/myApp/public/index.php(21): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#17 {main}
```

Previous exceptions:
PDO exception:

File:

```
/var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-db/src/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Statement.php:239
```

Message:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'myAppDatabase.User' doesn't exist
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-db/src/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Statement.php(239): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-db/src/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php(238): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement->execute()
#2 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-db/src/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php(208): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->executeSelect(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#3 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-db/src/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php(195): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->selectWith(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#4 /var/www/myApp/module/User/src/User/Model/UserTable.php(17): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->select()
#5 /var/www/myApp/module/User/src/User/Controller/UserController.php(40): User\Model\UserTable->fetchAll()
#6 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractRestfulController.php(370): User\Controller\UserController->getList()
#7 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#10 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractRestfulController.php(300): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#12 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#13 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#14 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#15 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#16 /var/www/myApp/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#17 /var/www/myApp/public/index.php(21): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#18 {main}
```

I will appreciate any help for resolving this error.

Forgive me if I am missing some information here and let me know if you need any more details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Are you really sure everything is configured correctly? :)*

If yes, then it could be that you changed to a system that is not case sensitive to a case sensitive system. Maybe you can go in your database (with phpmyadmin or similar to check if the table exist and the name corresponds). Or try to rename all tables to small characters (lowercase).

To avoid problems while moving/copying/migrating it is anyway advisable to only **use lowercase** names for **tables** and **columns**. So no camel-casing like you did but rather use underscores.

So try to for example to change the names to `my_app_database` (table) and `user` (column) and test if it works then.

Comment: Actually the table manes are all lowercase and this is strange for me that I  get 'User' in uppercase (in the message) though I the users table as 'user'.

Comment: @Zahra, Well at least you have your answer. Something wrong with the upper/lower casing of your table and column names :) It will be probably easy to find the problem now. Otherwise you can post some more details.

Comment: I guess the problem is from my code as I have all the tables names there in uppercase.